# Programmatically Manipulating App Icon Location on Android Devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, sdk, user-experience

**Is it possible to move and rearrange app icons within the home screen *using another app***?

Perhaps said more clearly, could an app help you organize the rest of your apps without using the native drag and drop function? (i.e. press a button and rearrange icons by title?)

I couldn't find any documentation or examples on this, but if anyone has an idea **IF** it's possible that would be great, an example would just be a bonus.

Thank so much,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to move and rearrange app icons within the home screen using another app?

Not in general. For starters, there is no requirement for a home screen to have "app icons", let alone ones that can be positioned by third parties. There is nothing in the Android SDK for this.

You are welcome to work with specific home screen authors, to see if they have some sort of an API that allows developers to write this sort of extension for their specific home screens.